# C++ know if disk/usb is FAT32 formatted with low level io code

Tags: c++, macos, io, disk, low-level

Is it possible to know if an USB has the FAT32 filesystem using low level IO on OSX, I've seen examples and stuff using win32 API, but I'm looking for some more low-level. Right now my FAT32 detection uses the terminal command 'diskutil' info /dev/mydisk is it possible to open the disk and read if it is FAT32 or any other filesystem?

Comment: If you have raw access to the disk, you can download specifications for FAT32 or whatever filesystem you want to detect and compare the headers.

Comment: @riv  where can i find that? and how would i use the information?

Answer (score 0):

Not low level, but you can use [getmntinfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getmntinfo.3.html) .

Iterate through statfs structs returned, matching the path where USB is mounted with statfs.f_mntonname or /dev/mydisk with statfs.f_mntfromname.

statfs.f_fstypename is the filesystem name, msdos for FAT.